# Remove Web Apps from migration path for Super User

Tags: discussion, migration

It seems to me that a third to one half of the questions migrated from [Super User](https://superuser.com) are incorrect migrations. (Here's [an example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102100).)

Should we lobby for Web Applications to be removed from Super User's set of default migration paths? (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Android Enthusiasts are the other paths.)

Answer (score 8):

As per the stats, it's actually 25% - there were total 149 migrations in the last 3 months and of that 84 were to Web Apps.

25% of 84 ~ 21 rejections over a span of 90 days is think not that big of a number.

[image]

Comment: I wonder how many migrations haven't been rejected simply because there aren't very many active question closers here. Stats don't lie, obviously, but it sure _feels_ like we get a lot more crap than good stuff from SU. How do our number _to_ them look?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to add to ale's question that the migration from Super User to Web Applications is frequently wrong both ways, that is that obvious migration candidate questions about Gmail or Facebook are mistakenly reviewed at Super User as off topic because "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center." so that a question that should be migrated to Web Applications isn't migrated.

What I could do to help solve the problem is to discuss the matter with the individual reviewers in a Super User chat room. When facing difficulties reviewing borderline questions I have obtained good results from asking other reviewers for advice about how to review the question in chat.